# How to resolve Joomla Fatal Error : JApplicationCms::getUserState()

Tags: joomla3.0

I got this error after Global Check In:

> Fatal error: JApplicationCms::getUserState() [japplicationcms.getuserstate]: The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "Joomla\Registry\Registry" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /home/societ/societ.us/libraries/cms/application/cms.php on line 504

I don't know where the problem is.

I'm currently using Joomla 3.2.3

It's fixed when I clear the cookies, but happens again when I'm navigating to Global Check In page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused due to active session (not closed properly) in the Joomla! sessions table.

Follow below steps to resolve these errors:

1. Login to cPanel.
2. Access the DB using PhPmyAdmin.
3. Delete all the user sessions from the 'vnto1_session' table.

Now website is accessible without any errors.

Comment: That problem can come back very easy right? I mean someone do not close session and here we are. What was your code? Or it is general Joomla error?

Comment: it is general Joomla error .. this error produce after installed extensions OR templates